# Android 401 gcm error while sending messages from server to device

Tags: android, python, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a message using gcm from server to device. 
This is my Python code using Python-requests

```
import requests
api_key = "xxx"
reg_id = "yyy"
url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization: key': api_key}
data = {"registration_ids":"[" + reg_id + "]"}

r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data = json.dumps(data))
```

This returns a 401 error for me.

The exact same key and registration id, when used in a curl statement, work perfectly fine.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `key=API-key`. I.e., the word `key` should be part of the value of the `Authorization` header.